# Recursive grep with piped input

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to recursively grep all of the .txt files within a directory:

```
grep -r --include \*.txt findThisStr .
```

Unfortunately, the .txt files I'm trying to search have some null characters in them and using the -a or --text flags seems to be causing matches on all the lines in the file. To remedy this, I was hoping to sanitize the input and pipe it through grep ([like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19911)), but I'm unsure how to do this recursively, or even if it's possible.

Essentially, I'd like to do something like this, except `file` would be dynamic:

```
   cat file | tr -d '\000' | grep -r --include \*.txt findThisStr .
```

I'm using grep on Windows 7 through the 64-bit MINGW shell.

Comment: You must have missed something, if "-a or --text flags seems to be causing matches on all the lines". If you have some sample code and input, we might understand the problem better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop over all *.txt files:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.txt'); do
    cat $i | tr -d '\000' | grep findThisStr
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.txt' |xargs grep -l findThisStr
```

Will find the files named .txt and print out the filenames with findThisStr in them.  If you have special characters in findThisStr  you should escape or quote them.